# What Makes the JAMStack Secure?

Tags: javascript, security, jamstack

Every description of the JAMstack seems to mention "security" as benefit, e.g.:

> The static nature of a JAMstack app makes scaling easy, and causes little to no dev-ops overhead. The JAMstack approach can also improve your app's security posture since static sites generally have a small attack vector.

https://www.contentful.com/r/knowledgebase/jamstack-cms/

> delivers better performance, higher security, lower cost of scaling, and a better developer experience.

https://jamstack.org/

I really don't understand what's "more secure" about it. All I am seeing are quotes like this:

> developers could leverage the expertise of third-party services to enhance the security features of your website/app

So, in short, is the only "security" here coming from the fact that `Auth0`, `Octa`, or whoever else is supposed to be good at security because it's their focus? Or am I missing something?

Edit, found one more quote:

> With no databases, plugins, or dynamic software running on your server, the potential for code injection and hacks is reduced enormously. When your website is a collection of static files, all dynamic functions are instead handled with APIs and client-side JavaScript, negating the need to rely on CMS plugins. While it’s entirely possible that an external API handling persistent data may expose a vulnerability, eliminating your CMS removes numerous points of failure and attack vectors. For static blogs, it’s not a stretch to say that security essentially becomes a non-issue, at least when compared to a typical WordPress installation.

https://builtvisible.com/go-static-try-jamstack/

So, it seems like most of the "security" is just not having wordpress?

Comment: Sounds very much like the default security advantages of [any static web page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_web_page), nothing special for Jamstack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that basically it.

Having "no wordpress" means:

- No [Wordpress](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-2337/product_id-4096/), [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/security), [Jumla](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-3496/product_id-16499/Joomla-Joomla-.html), [MySQL](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-185/product_id-316/Mysql-Mysql.html), etc...
- The webserver side ([IIS](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-26/product_id-3436/Microsoft-IIS.html), [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html), [Nginx](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-10048/product_id-17956/Nginx-Nginx.html)) maybe still here if you are not using 3rd party cdn but easier to update and mitigate because it only serve static files, no need to manage php \ python \ complicate cgi plugins and dependencies.
- No stored XSS, only [reflected](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Types_of_Cross-Site_Scripting).

It dramatically narrows down the attack surface.

Comment: OWASP's page on XSS is now here: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/